# Splitting filename and summing index

Tags: python, arrays, string, for-loop, indexing

I have a directory of files with a format like `test_001_3.wav`. The first number is just an ID whereas the second number is an index. I want to loop through these filenames and sum the index for each ID. For example, taking the following data

```
test_001_0.wav
test_001_1.wav
test_001_2.wav
test_002_0.wav
test_002_1.wav
```

Returned would be

```
total for test_001: 3
total for test_002: 2
```

My current code is below. It correctly sums the indexes however I don't know how to make it work for the entire array of filenames.

```
samples = []
for filename in filenames:
    file_id = filename.split('_')[1].split('.')[0]
    index = filename.split('_')[-1].split('.')[0]
    samples.append([file_id, index])
        
count=0
for sample in samples:
    if sample[0] == '001':
        count+=1

print(samples)  # [['001', '0'], ['001', '1'], ['001', '2'], ['002', '0'], ['002', '1']]   
print(count)    # 3
```

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thank you for the links. I have updated my question with my attempted implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pandas and assuming this is in a dataframe you could use something along this line:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\\Desktop\\test_xcel.xlsx', index_col=None, header=None)

df[0] = df[0].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-6])
df = df.groupby([0]).size().reset_index(name='count')
print(df)

          0  count
0  test_001      3
1  test_002      2
```

This is all assuming that the dataframe is formatted in an excel file and contains no column names.

Edit: To account for your current update to the question maybe try this out:

```
for k, g in itertools.groupby(files, key=lambda x:re.search('_(\d+)_', x).group(1)):
    print k, len(list(g))
```

Comment: My data is currently stored in an array from using os.listdir to scrape a directory for filenames. I was hoping it would be possible to do this with just python arrays. I've edited my question with my current implementation that is only partially working

Comment: If i were to have files in the format `24hfi86s_1.wav` (i.e. alphanumeric ID, underscore, then the index), how would I go about adjusting the regex expression you provided in your second solution? I have tried `lambda x:re.search('(\w+)_', x).group(1)` but this has not worked as expected. Any thoughts?